# Roboelectric 3.0 with Android Studio android.view.InflateException

Tags: gradle, robolectric

I recently moved to **Roboelectric** 3.0 and I cant get past a simple step to run a test which runs the following command:

```
@Config(sdk = 18, constants = BuildConfig.class) 
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class LegDetailActivityTest {
    @Test public void testThatLegDetailActivityCanBeInjected() {    

        LegDetailsActivity activity =
            Robolectric.buildActivity(LegDetailsActivity.class).create(bundle).get();

        graph.inject(activity);
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/layout/abc_screen_toolbar.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:299)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
```

My activity class is extended with `AppCompatActivity`.

My `build.gradle` has these dependencies:

```
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testCompile 'org.easytesting:fest:1.0.16'
  testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'
  testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
  testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
  }
  testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.0')
```

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Where do you get this error, in Android Studio, or on command line. Simple examples can be found at https://github.com/nenick/AndroidStudioAndRobolectric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was somewhere with the v4 library. I solved it by excluding v4 in my build.gradle.

```
 testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0') {
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
  }
```